# curious behavior of Combine framework removeDuplicates

Tags: swift, combine

Consider:

```
let test = [(1,true), (2,false), (3,false), (4,true), (5,true), (6,true)]
test.publisher.removeDuplicates { $0.1 != $1.1 }
    .sink { print($0.0) }
```

This is a sequence of (Int,Bool) pairs. What I'm trying to say in my `removeDuplicates` filter is: "Do not let through any pairs where the Bool changed from the previous Bool."

So what I expect is:

- `2` won't get through, because its `false` is different from the previous `true`
- `4` won't get through, because its `true` is different from the previous `false`

All the others should get through, so the result should be `1,3,5,6`.

But it isn't. It's `1,4,5,6`.

Can anyone explain why? What reasoning is `removeDuplicates` using here?

I *think* I know the answer; I think it is comparing the current value from upstream with the previous value *that was permitted to pass through the filter*. Thus, `1` gets through with its `true`, and then `2` and `3` are suppressed because their `false` is different from *that*.

But surely that's not right? Surely we should be comparing to the previous value *that came from upstream*?

[The docs are in fact oddly coy about this. They say "Publishes only elements that don’t match the previous element". I assumed that this meant "the previous element that arrived from upstream." But it seems instead that it means "the previous element that we actually published to the downstream"?]

Comment: Your assumption is exactly right. If you put a `print` inside the comparison closure, then you'll see it's exactly what's happening. And I think it makes sense too, because it ensures that the downstream doesn't get duplicates. It's just weird that your comparison is an inequality for something that should probably be an equality to test for duplication

Comment: @NewDev Sure, it's a weird test, but that's how I encountered this. If you don't put something interesting into the closure, you don't elicit the difference between "previous from upstream" and "previous passed to downstream".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `removeDuplicates` matches the behavior of its granddaddy, Rx.NET's `DistinctUntilChanged`, whose source code you can examine [here](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/7ad606b3dcd4bb2c6ae9622f8a59db7f8f52aa85/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable/DistinctUntilChanged.cs).

In a stream of “equal” values “a, a, a, …”, storing each new “a” as the prior value requires copying the value, and possibly adjusting reference counts (if it's a value type with reference properties). Holding on to the first “a” avoids that work.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know (i.e. is `.removeDuplicates` modelling its "inherited" behavior correctly). The key thing I'm after is to settle the equivocation of what constitutes a previous value. I assumed it was previous _from upstream_ but it appears to mean previous _passed downstream_. In the source code you pointed to, it looks like the lines `_currentKey = key; ForwardOnNext(value);` answers that: we memoize when and only when we pass a value downstream.